# Magento 1.7.0.2 : Custom layout update adding CSS

Tags: magento, layout, magento-1.7

I have magento 1.7.0.2 And a Category which iam unable to add a CSS in the Custom Layout update.

```
<reference name="head">
  <action method="addCSS">
    <type>css/ecoffice.css</type>
    <stylesheet>media="all"</stylesheet>
  </action>
  <action method="addCss">
    <stylesheet>css/ecoffice.css</stylesheet>
  </action>
  <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/ecoffice.css</name></action>
</reference>
```

This is what i am using and nether works.
How can i add custom CSS to a category that hold s a static page with a widget inside?
I want this to only 1 page, not all.

Comment: do you need this css on the category listing page ?

Comment: @PradeepSanku ona category page with only a static block display. And i want to add to that one specific page only

Answer (score 0):

If want ,i add

```
<catalog_category_layered>
 <reference name="head">
  <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/ecoffice.css</name></action>
    <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/ecoffice.css</stylesheet></action>
   </reference>
   </catalog_category_layered>

   <catalog_category_default>
 <reference name="head">
  <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/ecoffice.css</name></action>
    <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/ecoffice.css</stylesheet></action>
   </reference>
   </catalog_category_default>
```

Comment: Isnt this to a custom XML File? i only want to add the CSS to a specific page.

Answer (score 0):

add this code in the local.xml file of your theme.

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/ecoffice.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
        </reference>
<catalog_category_default>
```